# Linq ConcurrentDictionary Roles and Users Many to Many

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have POCO classes mapping the database tables: 
EDITED ------------------------------

```
class Role { string Id; ConcurrentDictionary<string, User> Users; }
class User { string Id; ConcurrentDictionary<string, Roles> Roles; }   
class RoleUser { string Id; string RoleId; string UserId; }
ConcurrentDictionary<string, Role> RolesDict;
ConcurrentDictionary<string, User> UsersDict;
ConcurrentDictionary<string, RoleUser> RoleUserDict;
```

I am using ORMLite from ServiceStack (it is some non-entity-framework lite ORM), so it doesn't seem have auto-relational-mapping to the collections. I make the Linq statement to map this Many-to-Many relationship between `Role-RU-User`. Here is the Linq:

```
//cleaning old data
UsersDict.ForEach(kvUser => kvUser.Value.Roles.Clear());
//for each role ...
RolesDict.ForEach(kvRole => {
    //cleaning old data
    kvRole.Value.Users.Clear();
    //find users that belong to the role
    var users = (from ru in RoleUserDict
         join u in UsersDict on ru.Value.UserId equals u.Value.Id
         where ru.Value.RoleId == kvRole.Value.Id 
         select u).ToList();
    //couple them up
    users.ForEach(kvUser => {
        kvRole.Value.Users.TryAdd(kvUser.Key, kvUser.Value);
        kvUser.Value.Roles.TryAdd(kvRole.Key, kvRole.Value);
    });
});
```

I am not good at Linq and I am not sure how normally the Many-to-Many relationship is handled in this situation. My code looks pretty horrible to me. Especially with those chunky nested ForEach() loops.

My Question is: Is there a more elegant approach with better looking code and better performance?

Thank you Linq & Lambda experts :D

Comment: Don't like it. If a lambda statement spans more than 2 lines, you probably want to refactor it into its own method

Comment: I might be missing something but ConcurrentDictionary takes 2 T's not one? shouldn't it be ConcurrentDictionary<User,?> maybe you want Users in Role to be a list? and Roles in User as well? in that case the linq could be easier

Comment: @Dmitry, sorry I am not clear enough. We have UsersDict<string, User>, RolesDict<string, Role>, and RoleUserDict<string, RoleUser> where T1 string is the Id, T2 is the actual object.

Comment: I understand, but what about your POCO's? that's the part I find confusing

Comment: My bad, wasn't declaring the variables clearly, edited already. So, any improvement suggestions?

Comment: sorry really thought I could improve on this with lambda's for select and join and rebuild the lists as opposed to cleaning them, but as it may look more elegant it becomes overly complicated to be maintainable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the linking I'd loop on the intermediate table and use the dicationary lookups to to access the user and roles.

```
UsersDict.ForEach(kvUser => kvUser.Value.Roles.Clear());

RolesDict.ForEach(kvRole => kvRole.Value.Users.Clear());

RoleUserDict.ForEach(kvRoleUser => {
    UsersDict[kvRoleUser.Value.UserId].Roles.TryAdd(kvRoleUser.Value.RoleId, RolesDict[kvRoleUser.Value.RoleId]);
    RolesDict[kvRoleUser.Value.RoleId].Users.TryAdd(kvRoleUser.Value.UserId, UsersDict[kvRoleUser.Value.UserId]);
});
```